# How to increase the number of items in the "recent" folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

Windows 7 keeps a list of recently used files in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`. Based on my observation, it keeps 10 items for each file extension. So when you So open 11 `.txt` files in a row, the 2nd to the 11th items will stay in that `Recent` folder, but the first one will be gone.

My question is: How to keep an unlimited number of items in that `Recent` folder?

Note: Increasing the per-application recent items (e.g. as in 
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/21/change-increase-or-decrease-number-of-recent-or-frequent-items-displayed-in-windows-7-taskbar-jump-list/ ) has no effect on the per-user `Recent` item folder that I'm concerning.

---

Solution: Edit (or create) the following registry key

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"MaxRecentDocs"=dword:00000100
```

Thank you Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article from How To Geek should help you:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-the-number-of-recent-items-shown-on-the-vista-start-menu/

It says it will work for 7 as well as Vista.